# Select row in Javafx Tableview

Tags: javafx-8

[image]

According to my above Table view once I click on any Action icon it will navigate to another window (with selected data). How I keep selected same row when it back again to this Table view. Thanks.

Comment: Ref this soloution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268529/javafx-tableview-keep-selected-row-in-current-view

Comment: @Reegan Thanks for the reply. Yes I have seen that one before, but it was bit complicated. It seems We can do this with,  TableView.getSelectionModel().select(itemIndex) or TableView.getFocusModel().focus(itemIndex) but not work properly. Thanks.

Comment: why does selection change, to start with? I would expect it to be the exact same when coming back from the other window (except when clicking somewhere else in the table). Please consider showing SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I think that the question is duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413419/javafx-2-how-to-focus-a-table-row-programmatically

Answer (score 5):

So sorry actually I have duplicated the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413419/javafx-2-how-to-focus-a-table-row-programmatically)

Correct answer was there:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        table.requestFocus();
        table.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        table.getFocusModel().focus(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: in fact table.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(0) is better than select(0) since it also clear previous selections.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the current selection (as a field) in your table view wrapper instance, and the restore it on re-focus.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Yes I have try both of this TableView.getSelectionModel().select(itemIndex) or TableView.getFocusModel().focus(itemIndex) but it was not highlighted table row as we highlighted with mouse (light dark blue colour). Thanks.