# JavaFx TableView row losing selection highlight

Tags: java, javafx

After selecting a row of a tableview in JavaFx by mouse click, the selection does not remain.

In respect to this I would like to bring it to notice that the table is being updated, the column values of **In Images** and **Out Images** are being updated based on the values in the database.

During update and even after updating the values, I **cannot keep the selection highlight on the particular row** that I am selecting.

Whenever I select a row, I can get the selected value by using `tableview.getSelectedModel.getSelectedItem()`, but the selection does not remain on the selected row.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem? Otherwise everyone is just blindly guessing at what you are doing in your code to cause this to happen.

Comment: @James_D : Have uploaded a video, please check if that helps. The link to the video is posted above. Thanx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to programatically select a row in the TableView after all the values have been updated. Refer to this question on how to select a Row.
 [Select row in Javafx Tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639386/select-row-in-javafx-tableview)

Here is an example of how you can apply this to your situation.

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(e->{
    int selectedRow = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    //... do all the updating and all that fun stuff.
    tableView.requestFocus();
    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(selectedRow);
    tableView.getFocusModel().focus(selectedRow);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you removing the old item and then adding the new item back?
If you are, that maybe causing the effect that you are seeing.
In FX in case of data updates you can just update the properties within the item and you do not need to remove item from the ObservableList backing the table.
However make sure that the item is updated from the FX thread and not any other thread.